# Insert variables in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, formatting

I would like some guidance on how to "functionalize" my Javascript code so that I can reduce the number of lines. Right now, as you can probably tell from the code, I am just copying, pasting and changing the keywords (which serve as names, ids and variables in my script).

In this section, I would like to change the final "3" to any number between 1 and 5 as we will need to collect this financial data on as many as five directors per company.

How do I set up the pass-through () in the first line "function calcNet3() {" so that the final "3" in the var(s) and in the document.getElementById("...") is adjusted accordingly? I am hoping to create just one "function calcNet()" which will be able to sort out the 1,2,3,4 or 5 as required.

Here is my function as it stands right now. It works...I would just like to make it more flexible. I understand that I will need to adjust the HTML onchange to fire the "3" parameter into the function brackets.

```
function calcNet3() {
    // at a .value so that we are getting the value out of the form boxes
var res1a3 = document.getElementById("residence1value3").value;
var res1b3 = document.getElementById("residence1debt3").value;
var res2a3 = document.getElementById("residence2value3").value;
var res2b3 = document.getElementById("residence2debt3").value;
var res3a3 = document.getElementById("residence3value3").value;
var res3b3 = document.getElementById("residence3debt3").value;
var inv1a3 = document.getElementById("invprop1value3").value;
var inv1b3 = document.getElementById("invprop1debt3").value;
var inv2a3 = document.getElementById("invprop2value3").value;
var inv2b3 = document.getElementById("invprop2debt3").value;
var inv3a3 = document.getElementById("invprop3value3").value;
var inv3b3 = document.getElementById("invprop3debt3").value;
var port13 = document.getElementById("shareport1value3").value;
var port23 = document.getElementById("shareport2value3").value;
var port33 = document.getElementById("shareport3value3").value;
var bank13 = document.getElementById("cash1value3").value;
var bank23 = document.getElementById("cash2value3").value;
var bank33 = document.getElementById("cash3value3").value;

// calculate net worth into a variable, put "+" in front of variable to make sure it is     a number
var nw3 = +res1a3 - +res1b3 + +res2a3 - +res2b3 + +res3a3 - +res3b3 + +inv1a3 - +inv1b3 + +inv2a3 - +inv2b3 + +inv3a3 - +inv3b3 + +port13 + +port23 + +port33 + +bank13 + +bank23 + +bank33;

// take the answer and feed it into the postFV function so that it gets added to the right span
postWorth3(nw3);
```

}

If this question has been asked and answered, please send me to the right place. I did search but unfortunately did not find an answer that fit.

Comment: Do all the related fields live in same row structure within html? Can often to this using a traverse of the DOM without a lot of code. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might need a little work on an architectural level -- you would probably be better suited to using something like knockout.js to setup a dynamic view model that could change your html dynamically as well... that being said -- to answer your immediate question on how to modify your function to accept a parameter and make it a bit more dynamic and simple:

just use an object to hold a dynamic number of properties...

```
function calcNet(numDirectors) {
    var formVals = {}, totalNet = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= numDirectors; i++) {
        formVals["res" + i + "a"] = document.getElementById('residence' + i + 'value').value;
        formVals["res" + i + "b"] = document.getElementById('residence' + i + 'debt').value;
        formVals["inv" + i + "a"] = document.getElementById("invprop" + i + "value").value;
        formVals["port" + i] = document.getElementById("shareport" + i + "value").value;
        formVals["bank" + i] = document.getElementById("cash" + i + "value").value;
        // you could use the '+' unary here like in your example, but I just like using Number() 
        formVals["net"+i] = Number(formVals["res" + i + "a"]) - Number(formVals["res" + i + "b"]) +
            Number(formVals["inv" + i + "a"]) + Number(formVals["bank" + i]);
        totalNet += formVals["net"+i];
    }
    // assuming you also modify postWorth to be a bit more dynamic!
    postWorth(totalNet);
}
```

Comment: John-o, Thanks. I hadn't thought about iterating through all the directors...probably a feature I should work up next. The main takeaway for me is that I can add in the required number within the structures to create the specific variables I need. Wasn't sure I could do that.

Comment: I would give you a plus vote but apparently I am too green to be trusted with this power. Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: @jgcrossman no problem! You might find more info on this sort of thing by looking for javascript dynamic variables or something like that, and just as an extra suggestion if you didn't care about individual values (just the net) you could add a class to each input (for asset or debt) then use querySelectorAll (or a jquery selector) to get every input matching the class... then you could just cycle through values in an array to add up your total

Comment: I see what you are saying although I have struggled with jquery on issues that are complex and specific to my needs. Javascript is clunky but gets the job done (with PHP, of course). In this case, I am building a new account form, know your client interview and a database load all in one. So, we need all the funny variables to complete our investor profiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o={ item:null, item2:null};
var sum=0;


for (var i in o){
  var val=whatever(i);
  o[i]= val;
  sum+=val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change calcNet() to use eval() so it can create variables based on the parameter supplied. It will also use the correct version of postWorth() based upon the parameter supplied.

```
function calcNet(x) {
    eval("var res1a" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence1value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var res1b" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence1debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var res2a" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence2value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var res2b" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence2debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var res3a" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence3value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var res3b" + x + " = document.getElementById('residence3debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv1a" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop1value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv1b" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop1debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv2a" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop2value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv2b" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop2debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv3a" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop3value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var inv3b" + x + " = document.getElementById('invprop3debt" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var port1" + x + " = document.getElementById('shareport1value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var port2" + x + " = document.getElementById('shareport2value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var port3" + x + " = document.getElementById('shareport3value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var bank1" + x + " = document.getElementById('cash1value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var bank2" + x + " = document.getElementById('cash2value" + x + "').value;");
    eval("var bank3" + x + " = document.getElementById('cash3value" + x + "').value;");

    eval("var nw" + x +  = '+res1a'+ x + '- +res1b'+ x + '+ +res2a'+ x + '- +res2b'+ x + '+ +res3a'+ x + '- +res3b'+ x + '+ +inv1a'+ x + '- +inv1b'+ x + '+ +inv2a'+ x + '- +inv2b'+ x + '+ +inv3a'+ x + '- +inv3b'+ x + '+ +port1'+ x + '+ +port2'+ x + '+ +port3'+ x + '+ +bank1'+ x + '+ +bank2'+ x + '+ +bank3' + x + ';');

    eval("postWorth" + x "(nw" + x + ");");
}
```

Comment: Definitely do NOT need eval here... highly recommend reading the MSDN blog series 'Eval is Evil' from Eric Lippert as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx